# kmalloc: only allocating 4 bytes

Tags: linux, kernel

So I am trying to dynamically allocate a buffer on module initialization. The buffer needs to be in scope at all times as it stores data that user space programs interact with. So here is my code:

```
static char* file_data
#define MAX_SIZE 256
.
.
.
{
   file_data = kzalloc(MAX_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL)

.
.
.
}
```

However when I do `sizeof file_data` it always returns 4. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: The buffer stores input from a user space program, but 4 characters is all that can be stored.

```
size_t read_file(char* __user buf, size_t count)
{
    unsigned int len = 0;
    len = copy_to_user(buf, file_data, count);
    return count;
}

ssize_t write_file(char* __user buf, size_t count)
{
    if(count >= MAX_SIZE)
        return -EINVAL;
    copy_from_user(file_data, buf,count)
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I guess I am learning what "dynamic allocation" is. My assumption was that the compiler could tell me the size information. I was wrong. Thanks guys for the answers though! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file_data` is a pointer.  On a 32-bit platform, it's size is 32 bits, or 4 bytes.  What you want to know is the size of **the data pointed to by `file_data`**.  You can't use the `sizeof` operator for this because `sizeof` is a compile time operation.  You can't use it on things allocated dynamically at run time.

(Besides, you already know the size of the data pointed to by `file_data` -- it's `MAX_SIZE`?)

Answer (score 3):

`char *file_data` is a pointer to a char. Evidently you're on a 32-bit system so any pointer is 4 bytes. The compiler (which handles `sizeof`) doesn't know or care how much memory you're allocating for `file_data` to point to, it just knows you're asking for the size of the pointer (which you are, whether you meant to or not). If you want the size of the memory it points to, you'll have to keep track of it yourself.